# REST ASSURED (JAVA): Extract json object value given it's parent object value

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Suppose I have the following json:

```
{
  "page": 2,
  "per_page": 3,
  "total": 12,
  "total_pages": 4,
  "data": [
 {
    "id": 4,
    "first_name": "Eve",
    "last_name": "Holt",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "first_name": "Charles",
    "last_name": "Morris",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "first_name": "Tracey",
    "last_name": "Ramos",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg"
}]}
```

I would like to extract only the value of "first_name" which belongs to id = 6.

I can overcome this with something else, but I want to know if there is a straight way with restassured

Something I have tried so far: 
data.find { it.id == '6' }.first_name

is it possible? If true, how to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: If course it's possible. Have you made any attempt to do so on your own?

Comment: Sure. no success. I can overcome this with something else, but I want to know if there is a straight way with restassured.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: data.find { it.id == '6' }.first_name

Comment: Please edit your question with that information. Part of the etiquette on SO is showing your work and asking complete standalone questions. Please don't take my comments as anything but an attempt to help you improve your question.

Comment: Which language are you using for Json processing - Java or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this solution will be what you are looking for but you can definitely extract the first name based on the id.

Use `JsonPath` library in `Rest Assured`. You can either pass JSON as a String `JsonPath.from("json string")` or you can get it from `Response` like this:

```
JsonPath path = response.jsonPath();
```

Then, you can get `data` array and iterate over its elements like this:

```
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> data = path.getList("data");
    for (HashMap<String, Object> singleObject : data) {
        if (singleObject.get("id").equals(6)) {
            System.out.println(singleObject.get("first_name"));
        }
    }
```

The above will print name "Tracey" to the console.
You can either work with this code or create a method to return parameter based on id like this:

```
    private static String getFirstNameById(JsonPath path, int id) {
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> data = path.getList("data");
        for (HashMap<String, Object> singleObject : data) {
            if (singleObject.get("id").equals(id)) {
                return (String) singleObject.get("first_name");
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException(String.format("Can't find first_name with id: %d", id));
    }
```

Just to make sure you understand - each of the element in `data` array is JSON Object. We collector all of the objects with method `getList`. Each of the object is represented by `HashMap` of `String` and `Object` because it contains different types. `first_name` is String and `id` is Integer, that's why we have to use HashMap of `Objects` as second generic argument.

Then we iterate over the HashMap, comparing `id` of each JSON Object to get desired results.

You can also use `Java Stream` if you'd like. The same method would look like this:

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> data = JsonPath.from(json).getList("data");
Optional<String> firstName = data.stream().filter(x -> x.get("id").equals(6)).map(x -> (String) x.get("first_name")).findFirst();
if (firstName.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(firstName.get());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below JsonPath, it will give you first_name based on id:

```
[?(@.id ==4)].first_name
```